# How to unselect shape in MS Word vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have shape selected in MS Word, I need to move the cursor out of the shape to the beginning of the document.
I tried all the following methods without any success.

```
     Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
     Selection.StartOf
     Selection.StartKey Unit:=wdStory
     Selection.Move
```

Comment: One rarely needs to *Select* anything with VBA, or to move the cursor. You should learn to use Range objects and other object identifiers.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Word environment so I used selection to paste pictures but finally I paste it using document.Content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select a different object, e.g. `ActiveDocument.Range(0,0).Select`.

However, you really need to avoid using the `Selection` object, it is hugely inefficient. Instead learn to manipulate the various objects directly.

Comment: It worked fine!
I usually avoid using selection but I had to use it to paste pictures.
After reading your answer I did some research and get rid of selection, so thank you for both the answer and the advice.